# How to get the parent thread in WinDBG?

Tags: multithreading, windbg

When I analyzed a crush dump file, I often got such errors:

```
0:025> kP
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`05a4fc78 00000000`77548638 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint(void) [d:\w7rtm\minkernel\ntos\rtl\amd64\debugstb.asm @ 51]
00000000`05a4fc80 00000000`774b39cb ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin(
   void * Context = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x38 [d:\w7rtm\minkernel\ntdll\dlluistb.c @ 310]
00000000`05a4fcb0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart(
   <function> * StartAddress = 0x00000000`00000000, 
   void * Argument = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x25 [d:\w7rtm\minkernel\ntos\rtl\rtlexec.c @ 3179]
```

It seems that the process crushed when creating a thread. So, I want to find who or which thread created the current thread. How can I get it?

Comment: I don't think the thread ID of the "parent" thread is saved automatically (or at least it is not readily available with the Windows API).  If you own the application, you could save that information.  On the other hand, it seems unlikely that the CreateThread call is causing the crash directly.  That would not be a very typical scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the other threads in the process with ~*k to see if there's anything interesting. Other than that, this info simply isn't there in the dump.

-scott